# Copy values from particular row to another

Tags: sql

I want to check if value of row2 is null then I copy value of row1 of same record into row2

I check using while loop if it is null then I copy value

```
Declare @val varchar(255) 
Select @val = row2 from student While(@val IS NULL) 
Begin
Update student Set row2 = (select row1 from student) 
End
 Go
```

Having subquery error cannot use = , < , >

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Why you name rows as columns, or vis-versa?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do something like this:

```
update student
    set row2 = row1
    where row2 is null ;
```

Your question is quite confusing because `row1` and `row2` are very strange names for columns.

Comment: For the name of my columns you're right. But want to loop through all records and update those having null as value –

Comment: @IbrahimSakho . . . SQL works on *sets*.  The `update` modifies all rows that meet the conditions.  No looping is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce`. In this way, if the value for `row2` is null the second argument (`row1`) is processed. By the way, using `col1`,`2` instead of `row 1`,`2` is better for column names, conventionally

```
Update student 
   Set row2 = coalesce(row2,row1) 
 Where id = @sid -- individual student ID
```

To apply for the whole set of data the filter `Where id = @sid` should be removed.

Comment: For the name of my columns you're right. But want to loop through all records and update those having null as value